# The program just stoped working when i type in the percentage

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

my problem is that in the following C-CODE nothing happens after i type in what percentage of cells should live at the start

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma warning (disable: 4996)

#define MAX_ROWS 20
#define MAX_COLS 30

typedef struct {
    char data[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
    int rows;
    int cols;
} Matrix;

char neighbor_count(Matrix* m, int row, int col) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= m->rows) {
            continue;
        }
        for (int j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++) {
            if (j < 0 || j >= m->cols) {
                continue;
            }
            if (m->data[i][j] == '*' && (i != row || j != col)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void check_cell(Matrix* m, int row, int col) {
    char neighbors_count = neighbor_count(m, row, col);
    char current_cell = m->data[row][col];

    if (neighbors_count < 2) { //Die Zelle stirbt an Vereinsamung
        m->data[row][col] = ' ';
    }
    else if (neighbors_count > 3 && current_cell == '*') { //Die Zelle stirbt an Übervölkerung
        m->data[row][col] = ' ';
    }
    else if (neighbors_count == 3 && current_cell == ' ') { //Aus der toten Zelle wird eine neue lebende Zelle
        m->data[row][col] = '*';
    }
    else if (neighbors_count == 2 || neighbors_count == 3) { //Die Zelle lebt weiter
        m->data[row][col] = '*';
    }
}

void load_from_file(Matrix* m, const char* filename) {
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("File not found\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int row_idx = 0;
    char ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF && row_idx < MAX_ROWS) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
            row_idx++;
            continue;
        }
        #
            m->data[row_idx][m->cols] = ch;
        m->cols++;
    }
    m->rows = row_idx;
    fclose(f);
}

void randomize(Matrix* m, int percent) {
    m->rows = MAX_ROWS;
    m->cols = MAX_COLS;
    int cells = (m->rows * m->cols) * (percent / 100.0f);
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (cells > 0) {
        int row = rand() % m->rows;
        int col = rand() % m->cols;
        if (m->data[row][col] == ' ') {
            m->data[row][col] = '*';
            cells--;
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(Matrix* m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->cols; j++) {
            printf("%c", m->data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void step(Matrix* m) {
    Matrix m_tmp = *m;
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->cols; j++) {
            check_cell(&m_tmp, i, j);
        }
    }
    *m = m_tmp;
}

int main() {
    Matrix m;

    // Menü zur Auswahl des Startzustands
    printf("1. Aus Datei laden\n");
    printf("2. Zufallszustand generieren\n");
    int selection;
    scanf("%d", &selection);

    switch (selection) {
    case 1: // Aus Datei laden
    {
        char  filename[20]; 
        printf("Bitte Dateinamen angeben: ");
        scanf("%s", filename);
        load_from_file(&m, filename);
        break;
    }
    case 2: // Zufallszustand generieren
    {
        int percent;
        printf("Prozentualer Anteil an lebenden Zellen: ");
        scanf("%d", &percent);
        randomize(&m, percent);
        break;
    }
    default:
        printf("Ungültige Eingabe\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Menü zur Auswahl der Animation
    printf("1. Schrittweise Animation\n");
    printf("2. Fließende Animation\n");
    scanf("%d", &selection);

    switch (selection) {
    case 1: // Schrittweise Animation
        while (1) {
            print_matrix(&m);
            step(&m);
            getchar();
        }
        break;
    case 2: // Fließende Animation
        while (1) {
            print_matrix(&m);
            step(&m);
            Sleep(200);
        }
        break;
    default:
        printf("Ungültige Eingabe\n");
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Translation:

```
1.load from file
2.  Generate Random State
2
Percentage of living cells: 10%
```

[image]

first i tought i just choose a number that is too high but i waitet like 30 minutes an nothing happend

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Hint: Where in your code do you accept the `%` character? `%d` is *strictly* digits.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf()` to detect parsing errors.

Comment: You just learned (or should have learned) that you ignore the return value of `scanf()` at your own risk.

Comment: OT: You cannot build the new generation using the same array as the old generation. You must preserve the old generation to analyse in order to correctly establish each cell of the new generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your matrix `data` is not initialized. It just contains random data or zeros. Because of this `if (m->data[row][col] == ' ')` might never be true, leading to an infinite loop.
When I modified the print routine and the chosen case like this:

```
void print_matrix(Matrix* m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLS; j++) {
                printf("%d ", (int)m->data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and

```
case 2: // Zufallszustand generieren
    {
        int percent;
        printf("Prozentualer Anteil an lebenden Zellen: ");
        int scanResult = scanf("%d", &percent);
        printf("scanf returned %d, percent value %d\n", scanResult, percent);
        print_matrix(&m);
        randomize(&m, percent);
        printf("randomization done\n");
        break;
    }
```

The output in some online compiler is

```
1. Aus Datei laden
2. Zufallszustand generieren
2
Prozentualer Anteil an lebenden Zellen: 10%
scanf returned 1, percent value 10
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 126 -86 85 -126 127 0 0 22 -121 64 -94 -45 102 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -112 113 -82 85 -126 127 0 0 -8 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -128 31 -83 85 
-126 127 0 0 -64 -38 -96 109 -3 127 0 0 -69 -57 -85 85 -126 127 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 -44 108 56 -23 82 -86 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 119 -82 85 -126 127 0 0 64 -123 -86 85 -126 127 0 0 96 113 -82 85 -126 127 
0 0 1 -39 -96 109 -3 127 0 0 -24 105 -82 85 -126 127 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 24 -78 
-81 109 -3 127 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -10 117 -82 3 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 64 2 
0 0 64 3 0 0 64 3 0 0 64 3 0 0 -128 3 0 0 -128 5 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 
-128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 
0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 
-128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 -128 9 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 64 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 4 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 64 -112 -57 22 -83 85 0 0 -1 -75 -16 0 0 0 0 0 -62 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -25 -38 
-96 109 -3 127 0 0 -26 -38 -96 109 -3 127 0 0 -115 -86 -57 22 -83 85 0 0 -24 98 -86 85 -126 127 0 0
```

A possible solution would be to insert

```
memset(m->data, (int)' ', MAX_COLS*MAX_ROWS);
```

into `randomize` before entering the loop.

This way the output up until the end of case 2 is (without the print_matrix modification)

```
1. Aus Datei laden
2. Zufallszustand generieren
2
Prozentualer Anteil an lebenden Zellen: 10%
scanf returned 1, percent value 10
   *  *              *        
                        *     
*                        *    
   *           *     *        
             *  *        *    
            *   *         *   
              **         *   *
              *      *       *
         *    *       *       
**     *          *           
          *         *    **   
    *                         
                **  *      *  
*  *  *   *      *       *    
         *                    
                              
     *               *        
         *      *             
        *      **  * *  **** *
            *                 

randomization done
```

Lastly, if you typed in a percent character after the value the next scanf under `// Menü zur Auswahl der Animation` tries to parse this as an integer and fails. You can see this when you print the return value of scanf which will be 0 because it couldn't parse the requested integer.

If you want the user to input a percent character you can modify the scanf request:

```
printf("Prozentualer Anteil an lebenden Zellen: ");
scanf("%d%%", &percent);
```

But then not inputting a percent character will stall.

Comment: Hey @knufy einundzwanzig very thank you for helping me here, can you tell me where do i need to put `memset(m->data, (int)' ', MAX_COLS*MAX_ROWS);´ and ´printf("Prozentualer Anteil an lebenden Zellen: ");scanf("%d%%", &percent);´

Comment: Hi, the memset statement can for example be the first line of the randomize function and the other two are a replacement for the two similar lines of case 2 (Zufallszustand generieren) right before the call to randomize. Did you understand what these lines change?

Comment: actually i didn't understand

Comment: Okay so what happens when you write `Matrix m;` is that you reserve some memory in your computer for the object m. This memory is not created however, it already existed with some values before object m. Because you don't know what objects occupied this memory before m, you can assume it to be random. Its contents are unclear. I assume you thought the `data` array was all whitespaces, right? In order to set it all to whitespace you can use memset. It sets each byte of your data to the argument you pass in. In this case a whitespace.